# How can I use non-deterministic igraph functions in a multithreaded program?

Tags: c, multithreading, igraph

I'm using the `igraph` C library in a multi-threaded program. Each of the threads creates a random graph using `igraph_barabasi_game`. Although the `IGRAPH_THREAD_SAFE` macro is set to 1, I'm still experiencing crashes which are apparently thread related.

Here's a minimal program which demonstrates the problem. I call the `do_work` function, which just creates a random graph, from two threads.

```
#include <pthread.h>                                                         
#include <igraph/igraph.h>                                                   

void *do_work(void *arg)                                                     
{                                                                            
    igraph_t g;                                                                 
    igraph_barabasi_game(&g, 100, 1, 4, NULL, 0, 1, 0, IGRAPH_BARABASI_PSUMTREE, NULL);
    igraph_destroy(&g);                                                      
}                                                                            

pthread_t threads[2];                                                        

int main (void)                                                              
{                                                                               
#if IGRAPH_THREAD_SAFE == 0                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "igraph is not thread safe\n");                             
    return 1;                                                                   
#endif                                                                          

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, do_work, NULL);                           
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, do_work, NULL);                           
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);                                             
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);                                             

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

This can be compiled with `gcc test.c -ligraph -lpthread`. This particular program doesn't crash, however when I run it through helgrind, there are errors related to the random number generator.

```
==20144== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x547D038 by thread #3
==20144== Locks held: none                                                      
==20144==    at 0x4F172A5: igraph_rng_mt19937_get (random.c:354)                
    ==20144==    by 0x4F17358: igraph_rng_mt19937_get_real (random.c:381)       
    ==20144==    by 0x4F17951: igraph_rng_get_unif (random.c:805)               
    ==20144==    by 0x4ED3F68: igraph_i_barabasi_game_psumtree (games.c:381) 
    ==20144==    by 0x400828: do_work (in /home/rmcclosk/test/a.out)            
    ==20144==    by 0x4C30E26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
    ==20144==    by 0x5488181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)              
    ==20144==    by 0x579847C: clone (clone.S:111)                              
    ==20144==                                                                   
    ==20144== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2       
    ==20144== Locks held: none                                                  
    ==20144==    at 0x4F17400: igraph_rng_mt19937_seed (string3.h:84)           
    ==20144==    by 0x4F177F1: igraph_rng_seed (random.c:684)                   
    ==20144==    by 0x4ED4354: igraph_i_barabasi_game_psumtree (games.c:340) 
    ==20144==    by 0x400828: do_work (in /home/rmcclosk/test/a.out)            
    ==20144==    by 0x4C30E26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
    ==20144==    by 0x5488181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)              
    ==20144==    by 0x579847C: clone (clone.S:111)
```

I think the solution would be to pass a different random number generator object to each thread, but I don't see a way to do that here, since `igraph_barabasi_game` doesn't take a generator as a parameter. Is there a proper way to use these non-deterministic functions in a multi-threaded program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: For updated information about using igraph in a multithreaded context, please see the [Using igraph in multi-threaded programs](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Advanced.html#using-igraph-in-multi-threaded-programs) section of the documentation.

---

*This is not really an answer yet but it's too long for a comment so I'm posting it as an answer*.

Thread-safety is still not guaranteed by igraph, although there were efforts that tried to replace global variables with thread-local ones. (That's what the `IGRAPH_THREAD_SAFE` macro does).

Internally, non-deterministic igraph functions that require the RNG call the `RNG_BEGIN()` macro to signal their intention to use the RNG (and then call `RNG_END()` to signal that they don't need the RNG any more). `RNG_BEGIN()` calls `igraph_rng_default()` to get hold of the "default" random number generator (and also seeds it if this is the first time the RNG is used). The race condition that `helgrind` identified possibly represents the seeding of the RNG by two threads at the same time. Interestingly enough, `igraph_rng_default()` returns the address of a thread-local struct (`igraph_i_rng_default`, see `src/random.c` in the source code), and this thread-local struct contains a flag that stores whether the RNG has been seeded already or not. On the other hand, the *state* of the RNG seems to be shared between threads, so what probably happens is that two or more threads try to mess around with the state vector of the *same* RNG because all the threads have their own thread-local flag that denotes whether the RNG is seeded.

If my hunch is correct, then the problems with the RNG can be solved by patching `src/random.c` and making `igraph_i_rng_default_state` thread-local by adding `IGRAPH_THREAD_LOCAL` to its declaration. Either way, this is definitely a bug in the current version of igraph, so you should [file an issue](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues) on Github.